# Cual es la manera correcta de utilizar enum java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Cómo puedo utilizar `enum` como roles para autenticarme en una app web java

```
public enum Role 
{
  ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER;
}
```

Estoy utilizando el framework de spring boot y así valido los roles:

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String defaultAfterLogin(HttpServletRequest request)
{  
    if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN") 
    {
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

Comment: aporta más datos, como recibe los datos tu app Web Java?

Comment: ya la edite brou estoy utilizando spring boot con spring security

Comment: ¿Recibes algún error? ¿Cómo no funciona lo que tienes?

Comment: Si funciona solo quiero ver como seria con enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## La forma correcta es de la

```
Public enum Role {

ROLE_ADMIN("ROLE_ADMIN"), ROLE_USER("ROLE_USER");
private String valor;

private Role(String valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}
public String getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(String valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

}
```

Ahora para utilizar el valor de cualquier posición en el se usa así

```
   String valores= Role.ROLE_ADMIN.getValor();
```